# WmK: Oh, Life Relax Please!

Tags: knowledge, english, language, word-ladder

"Oh, Life Relax Please!" is the title of a book about yoga that my Grandfather gifted me. This Wordmorph K is inspired by his love of wisdom and knowledge.

If you are not familiar with this kind of puzzle, you should read the rules first.

Rules: [Wordmorph K: An Introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66736/wordmorph-k-an-introduction)

> Start Word: LIFE
>
> Finish Word: RELAX
>
> K Score: 5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> LIFE -> LITE -> LITER -> LATER -> LAXER -> RELAX

I suspect that a K score of 4 may be possible.

Comment: Does the penultimate word have an entry?

Comment: Well, technically, MW redirects it to the page of "lax" instead. Not sure if that counts, but it does mean "to be more lax", and "-er" is a standard English construction so it might not be worth adding a separate page for it. (Not that it's relevant to the admission criteria, but it is indeed also Scrabble-playable.) (@kedarguru what are your thoughts on word forms?)

Comment: Laxer should count. I would be impressed if you achieved a score of 4.

Comment: Word forms seem okay in general, but I am not sure if there are some weird cases that I wouldn’t accept. I will keep it to my discretion for now.

Comment: Also — do you have any advice on how I can make these puzzles more challenging? these are much easier to solve than I anticipated.

Comment: @kedarguru Laxer is definitely a word, and the redirect indicates that Merriam-Webster agrees, but it looks like they forgot to actually include the word anywhere!

Comment: @kedarguru A long unique solution path with the possibility for wrong choices at each step. And the wrong choices work for several steps. The solution could also be unintuitive, especially having to move farther away from the final answer.

Comment: @kedarguru The puzzle is a shortest path problem with the heuristic that words sharing more letters are closer. If steps in the solution have a worse heuristic than alternatives (e.g., eliminating a common letter), then the solution will be harder to find.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78433/discussion-between-kedarguru-and-noedne).

Comment: I wrote a quick computer program to determine the minimum path length  between LIFE and RELAX under these rules.  It appears that a score of 4 is not possible, at least with the dictionary I used.

Answer (score 9):

> LIFE → [LIRE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lire) (plural of old Italian currency) → LYRE → RELY → RELAY → RELAX

Comment: This was actually my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

> LIFE → LIME → LAME → LAMER → LAXER → RELAX